# How to make every single value of array suitable in IF statement?

Tags: javascript

For example i have an array with 100 values, let it be a[1,2,3...100]
Can I create a if check that will be suitable for any value from the array?
like:

```
if(value === a[any index]){
//do smth
}
```

almost sure that it can be done but don't know how, can you help me with that?

Comment: Are you trying to find out if the value is in the array? Try this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: @Meow_ly no no, I'm trying to satisfy IF statement if the value matches any value from an array

Comment: `if (a.includes(value)) { /*do smth*/ }`

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli this is better than the posted answer Id say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
a.forEach(element => {
  if (value === element) {
    // do something
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you, that's really genius solution

Comment: This runs the if statement for each of the items in the array, is that what you're looking for, @Vladeezy?

Answer (score 1):

```js
// for of
for (const item of a) {
  if (value === item) {

  }
}

// traditional for loop
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (value === array[i]) {

  }
}

// forEach
a.forEach(item => {
  if (value === array[i]) {

  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the ES7 [`array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). If it finds a given value in your  array it will return a `True` boolean, else it will return `False`.

Example:

```js
console.log([1,2,3].includes(2)) //True

console.log([1,2,3,4,5].includes(6)) //False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `Object` or `Array` to hold functions as values and then lookup a specific function depending on a given value to run different code based on that value.

```js
function doSomething(){console.log("Something")}
function doSomethingElse(){console.log("Something else")}
function doAnotherThing(){console.log("Another thing")}

// specify value when to run a certain function and the function to run
const whatToDo = {
  "x": doSomething,
  "y": doSomethingElse,
  "z": doAnotherThing
}

// depending on some value the appropriate function will be run
const someValue = "z";
whatToDo[someValue]();

// or when using indices
const whatToDoArray = [doSomething, doSomethingElse, doAnotherThing];

// choose a function randomly
const randomValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * whatToDoArray.length);
whatToDoArray[randomValue]();
```